# Lightning Design System: Dates displaying as DateTime Output

Tags: lightning-design-system

I'm using the LDS for utilising the Lightning CSS on our VisualForce page but for some reason our Date field is being converted to a DateTime Output in my VF Page.

Below is the VisualForce piece - apologies if this is a basic question - I'm somewhat of a newbie on the LDS front.

```
<li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
<p class="slds-text-title slds-truncate slds-m-bottom--xx-small" title="Start Date">Start Date</p>
<p class="slds-text-body--regular slds-truncate" title="Start-Date-Field" value="2000-01-01"><{!proposal.SBQQ__StartDate__c}"/></p>
```

The field output is shown below [image]

Thank you for any help you can provide - appreciate it!

Comment: you could use ui:outputDate for displaying formatted date

Comment: `ui:outputDate` is a Lightning Component. This question is about Visualforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lightning Design System itself isn't in the business of formatting data. Instead, you will want to use an `<apex:outputField value="{!proposal.SBQQ__StartDate__c}" />` to display the data inside your SLDS markup. This should only render a `<span>` with the formatted DateTime value inside.